# How to implement cursor based pagination in graphql Apollo client?

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I am following the [official docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/pagination/#cursor-based) for cursor based Apollo Client implementation. I have already done the offset based pagination but cursor based seemed to be better fit in my case. The very first line is giving an error

`const { data: { comments, cursor }, loading, fetchMore } = useQuery(
    MORE_COMMENTS_QUERY
  );`

`cannot read property 'comments' of undefined`. This must be because data is still undefined. Is the documentation missing something or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the docs. You should either provide a default value for data:

```
const { data: { comments, cursor } = {}, loading, fetchMore } = useQuery(...)
```

or else check whether it exists before accessing properties on it.

```
const { data, loading, fetchMore } = useQuery(...)
if (data) {
  const { comments, cursor } = data
}
```

The latter is preferred because depending on the schema, it's possible for the query to complete and the data to be `null` (if you had errors in the response) and the default value won't be applied if `data` is `null`, only if it's `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Now the first part is working. Now I am having some problem in `onEndReached` function of Flatlist. This seems to be due to `cursor`. Does this `cursor` needs to be returned as part of data from server or can we calculate it on the client like `const cursor = data.someFeild[someIndex].a`  and use it later in `fetchMore()`